# Powershell Check MIME exists in IIS

Tags: powershell, iis, mime

I've got the following command to add a `MIME` type to `IIS` using `PowerShell`

```
add-webconfigurationproperty //staticContent -name collection -value @{fileExtension='.xpa'; mimeType='application/octet-stream'}
```

How can I check if the MIME type exists first before invoking `add-webconfigurationproperty`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check with the following:

```
if( !((Get-WebConfiguration //staticcontent).collection | ? {$_.fileextension -eq '.xpa'}) ) {
  #do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also check for the existence of a 'property' using this:

```
if (!(Get-WebConfigurationProperty //staticContent -Name collection[fileExtension=".xpa"])) 
{ 
    Write-Host ".xpa doesn't exist"
}
```